# Arduino Mega with Sensors and tftlcd 2.4 inch

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, sensors, lcd

I am working with tftlcd 2.4 inch with Arduino mega 2560 board. In this code I just want to show clock as my default or home screen. By clicking on clock at any point on screen user should get a new screen in which options of three sensors(pulse oximeter, glucose sensor and pedometer) are available. By selecting any sensor by touch, the value of that sensor will appear on screen. I also want to use Bluetooth module to send data to my mobile application. I did separate integration of all these sensors with Bluetooth module HC -06, but now I want to compile my all work. I have write a code for all this procedure which is given below:

```
    #include <Adafruit_GFX.h>   

#include <Adafruit_TFTLCD.h>
#include <TouchScreen.h>
//#include <URTouch.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "MAX30105.h"
#include "spo2_algorithm.h"

MAX30105 particleSensor;

#define YP A2                                                                                                                             
#define XM A3
#define YM 8 
#define XP 9
#define TS_MINX 275
#define TS_MINY 648
#define TS_MAXX 1023
#define TS_MAXY 623
#define MINPRESSURE 10
#define MAXPRESSURE 1000
#define LCD_CS A3
#define LCD_CD A2
#define LCD_WR A1
#define LCD_RD A0
#define LCD_RESET A4
#define MAX_BRIGHTNESS 255

TouchScreen ts = TouchScreen(XP, YP, XM, YM, 300);
Adafruit_TFTLCD tft(LCD_CS,LCD_CD, LCD_WR, LCD_RD, LCD_RESET);

#if defined(__AVR_ATmega328P__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega168__)
uint16_t irBuffer[100]; 
uint16_t redBuffer[100]; 
#else
uint32_t irBuffer[100]; 
uint32_t redBuffer[100];  
#endif

boolean buttonEnabled =true;
char currentpage, currentpcolour;
bool running;
//clock
uint16_t osx = 120, osy = 120, omx = 120, omy = 120, ohx = 120, ohy = 120, xpos; 
uint32_t targetTime = 0;          
uint8_t conv2d(const char* p) {
  uint8_t v = 0;
  if ('0' <= *p && *p <= '9')
    v = *p - '0';
  return 10 * v + *++p - '0';
}
uint8_t hh = conv2d(__TIME__), mm = conv2d(__TIME__ + 3), ss = conv2d(__TIME__ + 6); 
boolean initial = 1;
char d;

//PulseOxi
int32_t bufferLength, spo2, heartRate; //data length, SPO2 value, heart rate value
int8_t validSPO2, validHeartRate; //indicator to show if the SPO2 calculation is valid, indicator to show if the heart rate calculation is valid
byte pulseLED = 11; //Must be on PWM pin
byte readLED = 13; //Blinks with each data read 
byte ledBrightness = 60; //Options: 0=Off to 255=50mA
byte sampleAverage = 4; //Options: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32
byte ledMode = 2; //Options: 1 = Red only, 2 = Red + IR, 3 = Red + IR + Green
byte sampleRate = 100; //Options: 50, 100, 200, 400, 800, 1000, 1600, 3200
int pulseWidth = 411; //Options: 69, 118, 215, 411
int adcRange = 4096; //Options: 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384

//Pedometer
const int xpin = A1;
const int ypin = A2;
const int zpin = A3;
byte p[8] = {
  0x1F,
  0x1F,
  0x1F,
  0x1F,
  0x1F,
  0x1F,
  0x1F,
  0x1F
};
float threshold = 100;
float xval[100] = {0};
float yval[100] = {0};
float zval[100] = {0};
float xavg, yavg, zavg;
int steps, flag = 0;

void drawClock(){
  tft.setTextColor(0xFFFF);
  tft.fillScreen(0x0000);
  xpos = tft.width() / 2; 
  tft.drawCircle(xpos, 120, 125, 0xFFE0);
  tft.fillCircle(xpos, 120, 118, 0x001F); 
  tft.fillCircle(xpos, 120, 110, 0x0000); 
  for (int a=95; a<104; a++){
    tft.drawCircle(xpos, 120, a, 0xFFFF);
  }  
  for (int i = 0; i < 360; i += 30) {
    tft.drawLine(((cos((i - 90) * 0.0174532925)) * 114 + xpos), ((sin((i - 90) * 0.0174532925)) * 114 + 120), ((cos((i - 90) * 0.0174532925)) * 100 + xpos), ((sin((i - 90) * 0.0174532925)) * 100 + 120), 0xFFE0);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 360; i += 6) { 
    tft.drawPixel(((cos((i - 90) * 0.0174532925)) * 102 + xpos), ((sin((i - 90) * 0.0174532925)) * 102 + 120), 0x07E0); 
    tft.drawLine(((cos((i - 90) * 0.0174532925)) * 102 + xpos), ((sin((i - 90) * 0.0174532925)) * 102 + 120), ((cos((i - 90) * 0.0174532925)) * 92 + xpos), ((sin((i - 90) * 0.0174532925)) * 92 + 120), 0x0000);
    tft.drawLine(((cos((i - 90) * 0.0174532925)) * 102 + xpos)+1, ((sin((i - 90) * 0.0174532925)) * 102 + 120)+1, ((cos((i - 90) * 0.0174532925)) * 92 + xpos)+1, ((sin((i - 90) * 0.0174532925)) * 92 + 120)+1, 0x0000);

    if (i == 0 || i == 180) tft.fillCircle(((cos((i - 90) * 0.0174532925)) * 102 + xpos), ((sin((i - 90) * 0.0174532925))* 102 + 120), 2, 0xFFFF); 
    if (i == 90 || i == 270) tft.fillCircle(((cos((i - 90) * 0.0174532925)) * 102 + xpos), ((sin((i - 90) * 0.0174532925))* 102 + 120), 2, 0xFFFF); 
  }
  tft.fillCircle(xpos, 121, 3, 0xFFFF);
  targetTime = millis() + 1000;
}

void setup() {
  tft.reset();  
  tft.begin(0x9341); 
  tft.setRotation(1);
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  //TSPoint p = ts.getPoint();     // Read touchscreen
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  pinMode(XM, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(YP, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pulseLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(readLED, OUTPUT);
  //first screen
  drawClock();
  currentpage = '0';
}

void loop() {
if (currentpage == '0') {
  TSPoint p = ts.getPoint();
  if (p.z > ts.pressureThreshhold) {
      p.x = map(p.x,TS_MAXX, TS_MINX , 0, 320);
      p.y = map(p.y,TS_MAXY, TS_MINY , 0, 480);
      if (p.x > 50 && p.x > 260 && p.y > 180 && p.y < 270 && buttonEnabled){
        buttonEnabled = false;
        tft.fillScreen(0x0000);
        currentpage = '1';
        drawHomeScreen();
      }
  }
}
   if (currentpage == '1') {
    TSPoint p = ts.getPoint();
     if (p.z > 10 && p.z < 1000) {
        if (p.x > 736 && p.x < 855 && p.y > 255 && p.y < 725  && p.z > MINPRESSURE && p.z < MAXPRESSURE)
        {
        Serial.println("Pedometer");
        currentpage = 2;
        calibrate();
      }
      else if (p.x > 563 && p.x < 683 && p.y > 275 && p.y < 750)
      {
        currentpage = 3;
        //drawGlu();
      }
      if (p.x > 403 && p.x < 525 && p.y > 271 && p.y < 725)
      {
        if (!particleSensor.begin(Wire, I2C_SPEED_FAST)) //Use default I2C port, 400kHz speed
             {
              Serial.println(F("MAX30105 was not found. Please check wiring/power."));
              while (1);
             }
             Serial.println(F("Attach sensor to finger with rubber band. Press any key to start conversion"));
             while (Serial.available() == 0) ; //wait until user presses a key
             Serial.read();
             particleSensor.setup(ledBrightness, sampleAverage, ledMode, sampleRate, pulseWidth, adcRange); //Configure sensor with these settings
             currentpage = '4';
             drawPulseOxi();
      }
    }
  }
if (currentpage == '0') { 
    if (targetTime < millis()) {          
      targetTime = millis() + 1000;
      ss++;              
      if (ss == 60) {
        ss = 0;
        mm++;            
        if (mm > 59) {
          mm = 0;
          hh++;          
          if (hh > 23) {
            hh = 0;
        }
      }
    }
 if (ss == 0 || initial) {
      initial = 0;
      // Erase hour and minute hand positions every minute
      tft.drawLine(ohx, ohy, xpos, 121, 0x0000);
      ohx = (cos(((hh * 30 + (mm * 6 + (ss * 6) * 0.01666667) * 0.0833333) - 90) * 0.0174532925)) * 62 + xpos + 1;
      ohy = (sin(((hh * 30 + (mm * 6 + (ss * 6) * 0.01666667) * 0.0833333) - 90) * 0.0174532925)) * 62 + 121;
      tft.drawLine(omx, omy, xpos, 121,  0x0000);
      omx = (cos(((mm * 6 + (ss * 6) * 0.01666667)- 90) * 0.0174532925)) * 84 + xpos;
      omy = (sin(((mm * 6 + (ss * 6) * 0.01666667) - 90) * 0.0174532925)) * 84 + 121;
    }
      // Redraw new hand positions, hour and minute hands not erased here to avoid flicker
      tft.drawLine(osx, osy, xpos, 121,  0x0000);
      osx = (cos(((ss * 6) - 90) * 0.0174532925)) * 90 + xpos + 1;
      osy = (sin(((ss * 6) - 90) * 0.0174532925)) * 90 + 121;
      tft.drawLine(osx, osy, xpos, 121, 0xF800);
      tft.drawLine(ohx, ohy, xpos, 121, 0x07FF);
      tft.drawLine(omx, omy, xpos, 121, 0xFFFF);
      tft.drawLine(osx, osy, xpos, 121, 0xF800);
      tft.fillCircle(xpos, 121, 3, 0xF800);
      tft.setCursor(xpos-27, 50);
      tft.setTextSize(2);
      tft.print("Glucoxy");
 
  // Draw MINI clock face "SECOND"
  tft.drawCircle(xpos, 155, 20, 0xFFE0);
  tft.drawCircle(xpos, 155, 18, 0x001F);
  tft.drawCircle(xpos, 155, 17, 0x07FF);
  tft.drawCircle(xpos, 155, 16, 0x07FF);
  tft.fillRect(xpos-10, 149,22,15,0x0000); //erase
  if(ss<10){tft.setCursor(xpos-10, 149); tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print('0'); tft.setCursor(xpos+2, 149);}
  else{
  tft.setCursor(xpos-10, 149);}
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print(ss);
  // Draw MINI clock face "Minutes"
  tft.drawCircle(xpos+35, 117, 20, 0xFFE0);
  tft.drawCircle(xpos+35, 117, 18, 0x001F);
  tft.drawCircle(xpos+35, 117, 17, 0x07FF);
  tft.drawCircle(xpos+35, 117, 16, 0x07FF);
  tft.fillRect(xpos+25, 111,22,15, 0x0000); //erase
  if(mm<10){tft.setCursor(xpos+25, 111); tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print('0'); tft.setCursor(xpos+37, 111);}
  else{
  tft.setCursor(xpos+25, 111);}
  tft.println(mm);
  // Draw MINI clock face "Hour"
  tft.drawCircle(xpos-35, 117, 20, 0xFFE0);
  tft.drawCircle(xpos-35, 117, 18, 0x001F);
  tft.drawCircle(xpos-35, 117, 17, 0x07FF);
  tft.drawCircle(xpos-35, 117, 16, 0x07FF);
  tft.fillRect(xpos-45, 111,22,15,0x0000); //erase
  if(hh<10){tft.setCursor(xpos-45, 111); tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print('0'); tft.setCursor(xpos-33, 111);}
  else{
  tft.setCursor(xpos-45, 111);}
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print(hh);
  //tft.setCursor(xpos-65, 111);
  //tft.println(':');
  if (hh>=0 && hh<12) d='A'; else {d='P';}
  tft.drawRoundRect(xpos-14,72,29,21,5,0x07FF);
  tft.fillRect(xpos-11, 75,23,15,0x0000); //erase
  tft.setCursor(xpos-11, 75);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print(d);
  tft.println('M');
  }
}
if (currentpage == '2') 
{ 
    getPedo();
    TSPoint p = ts.getPoint();
    if (p.z > ts.pressureThreshhold) 
    {
      p.x = map(p.x,TS_MAXX, TS_MINX ,0,320);
      p.y = map(p.y,TS_MAXY, TS_MINY ,0,480);
      if (p.x > 50 && p.x > 260 && p.y > 180 && p.y < 270 && buttonEnabled)
      {
         tft.fillScreen(0x0000);
         currentpage = '1';
         drawHomeScreen();
      }
    
   }
}
if (currentpage == '3') 
{
     getGlucose();
     TSPoint p = ts.getPoint();
    if (p.z > ts.pressureThreshhold) 
    {
      p.x = map(p.x,TS_MAXX, TS_MINX ,0,320);
      p.y = map(p.y,TS_MAXY, TS_MINY ,0,480);
      if (p.x > 50 && p.x > 260 && p.y > 180 && p.y < 270 && buttonEnabled)
      {
         tft.fillScreen(0x0000);
         currentpage = '1';
         drawHomeScreen();
       }
     } 
}
if (currentpage == '4') 
{ 
    getPulse();
    TSPoint p = ts.getPoint();
    if (p.z > ts.pressureThreshhold) 
    {
      p.x = map(p.x,TS_MAXX, TS_MINX ,0,320);
      p.y = map(p.y,TS_MAXY, TS_MINY ,0,480);
      if (p.x > 50 && p.x > 260 && p.y > 180 && p.y < 270 && buttonEnabled)
      {
         tft.fillScreen(0x0000);
         currentpage = '1';
         drawHomeScreen();
      }
    } 
}

}

void drawHomeScreen(){
  tft.fillScreen(0x0000);
  tft.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 319, 240, 8, 0xFFE0);     //Page border

  tft.fillRoundRect(60, 180, 200, 40, 8, 0x001F);
  tft.drawRoundRect(60, 180, 200, 40, 8, 0xFFE0);  //PEDO

  //tft.fillRoundRect(60, 130, 200, 40, 8, 0x001F);   //Glu
 // tft.drawRoundRect(60, 130, 200, 40, 8, 0xFFE0);

  tft.fillRoundRect(60, 80, 200, 40, 8, 0x001F);
  tft.drawRoundRect(60, 80, 200, 40, 8, 0xFFE0); //Pulse oxi and heart rate

  tft.setCursor(25, 20);
  tft.setTextSize(3);
  tft.setTextColor(0xFFFF);
  tft.print("Welcome Here..");
  tft.setCursor(25, 50);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.setTextColor(0xFFE0);
  tft.print("Choose Your Sensor");
  tft.setTextColor(0x0000);
  tft.setCursor(110, 195);
  tft.print("Pedometer");
  //tft.setCursor(80, 145);
  //tft.print("Glucose Sensor");
  tft.setCursor(80, 95);
  tft.print("Pulse Oximeter");
}
void drawPulseOxi()
{
  tft.setTextColor(0x0000);
  tft.fillRoundRect (60, 180, 200, 40, 8,0x0000);
  tft.setTextColor(0x001F);
  tft.drawRoundRect (10, 10, 60, 36, 8, 0x0000);
  tft.setCursor(18, 15);
  tft.setTextSize(3);
  //tft.fillScreen(0x0000);
  tft.print("<-" );
  tft.setCursor( 70, 18);
  //tft.fillScreen(0x0000);
  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.print("Back to Main Menu");
  tft.setCursor( 70, 18);
  tft.setTextSize(3);
  tft.print("Pulse Oximeter & Heart rate Sensor");
  tft.print("MAX30102");
  tft.setTextColor(0xFFFF);
  tft.drawLine(0,100,319,100, 0xFFFF);
  
  }
  void getPulse()
  {
    bufferLength = 100; //buffer length of 100 stores 4 seconds of samples running at 25sps
    for (byte i = 0 ; i < bufferLength ; i++)
   {
    while (particleSensor.available() == false) //do we have new data?
           particleSensor.check(); //Check the sensor for new data

    redBuffer[i] = particleSensor.getRed();
    irBuffer[i] = particleSensor.getIR();
    particleSensor.nextSample(); 
    Serial.print(F("red="));
    Serial.print(redBuffer[i], DEC);
    Serial.print(F(", ir="));
    Serial.println(irBuffer[i], DEC);
   }

  maxim_heart_rate_and_oxygen_saturation(irBuffer, bufferLength, redBuffer, &spo2, &validSPO2, &heartRate, &validHeartRate);

  while (1)
  {
    for (byte i = 25; i < 100; i++)
    {
      redBuffer[i - 25] = redBuffer[i];
      irBuffer[i - 25] = irBuffer[i];
    }

    for (byte i = 75; i < 100; i++)
    {
      while (particleSensor.available() == false) //do we have new data?
        particleSensor.check(); //Check the sensor for new data

      digitalWrite(readLED, !digitalRead(readLED)); //Blink onboard LED with every data read

      redBuffer[i] = particleSensor.getRed();
      irBuffer[i] = particleSensor.getIR();
      particleSensor.nextSample(); //We're finished with this sample so move to next sample

      //send samples and calculation result to terminal program through UART
      Serial.print(F("red="));
      Serial.print(redBuffer[i], DEC);
      Serial.print(F(", ir="));
      Serial.print(irBuffer[i], DEC);

      Serial.print(F(", HR="));
      Serial.print(heartRate, DEC);

      Serial.print(F(", HRvalid="));
      Serial.print(validHeartRate, DEC);

      Serial.print(F(", SPO2="));
      Serial.print(spo2, DEC);

      Serial.print(F(", SPO2Valid="));
      Serial.println(validSPO2, DEC);
    }

    //After gathering 25 new samples recalculate HR and SP02
     maxim_heart_rate_and_oxygen_saturation(irBuffer, bufferLength, redBuffer, &spo2, &validSPO2, &heartRate, &validHeartRate);
       tft.setCursor(77,20);
       tft.setTextColor(0x0000);
       tft.println("Oxygen level is:");
       tft.setCursor(77,23);
       tft.println(spo2);
       tft.setCursor(97,20);
       tft.setTextColor(0x0000);
       tft.println("Heart Rate is:");
       tft.setCursor(77,23);
       tft.println(heartRate);
    
}
}
void calibrate(){
  float sum = 0, sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    xval[i] = float(analogRead(xpin) - 345);
    sum = xval[i] + sum;
  }
  delay(100);
  xavg = sum / 100.0;
  Serial.println(xavg);
  for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
  {
    yval[j] = float(analogRead(ypin) - 346);
    sum1 = yval[j] + sum1;
  }
  yavg = sum1 / 100.0;
  Serial.println(yavg);
  delay(100);
  for (int q = 0; q < 100; q++)
  {
    zval[q] = float(analogRead(zpin) - 416);
    sum2 = zval[q] + sum2;
  }
  zavg = sum2 / 100.0;
  delay(100);
  Serial.println(zavg);
  
}
void getPedo(){
  int acc = 0;
  float totvect[100] = {0};
  float totave[100] = {0};
  float xaccl[100] = {0};
  float yaccl[100] = {0};
  float zaccl[100] = {0};
  for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++)
  {
    xaccl[a] = float(analogRead(xpin) - 345);
    delay(1);
    yaccl[a] = float(analogRead(ypin) - 346);
    delay(1);
    zaccl[a] = float(analogRead(zpin) - 416);
    delay(1);
    totvect[a] = sqrt(((xaccl[a] - xavg) * (xaccl[a] - xavg)) + ((yaccl[a] - yavg) * (yaccl[a] - yavg)) + ((zval[a] - zavg) * (zval[a] - zavg)));
    totave[a] = (totvect[a] + totvect[a - 1]) / 2 ;
    Serial.println("totave[a]");
    Serial.println(totave[a]);
    delay(100);
    if (totave[a] > threshold && flag == 0)
    {
      steps = steps + 1;
      flag = 1;
    }
    else if (totave[a] > threshold && flag == 1)
    {
      // Don't Count
    }
    if (totave[a] < threshold   && flag == 1)
    {
      flag = 0;
    }
    if (steps < 0) {
      steps = 0;
    }
    Serial.println('\n');
    Serial.print("steps: ");
    Serial.println(steps);
    delay(1000);

    tft.setCursor(77,10);
    tft.println("steps: ");
    tft.print(steps);
    

  }
  delay(1000);
}
void drawGlucose(){
  
}
void getGlucose(){
  
}
```

The problem I am facing here is that, when code is uploaded, then at start clock appear only for 2 sec then screen becomes white and nothing else is appeared on screen. Please point out my mistake in code given above. I give this code my full try but cannot get desired results.

Comment: Start removing stuff that isn't involved in demonstrating the problem.  The more you remove, the more likely you are to get help.